# Regex in R: How to extract citations from manuscript

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to extract citations as precisely and exhaustively as possible from a manuscript using regex in R (so I don't have to do it manually).
Arguably the most defining feature of citations is the co-occurrence of an author's name identifiable via the upper case letter with which it starts as well as the year given in parentheses, e.g., `Name (2020)`. But there are numerous variants to this basic pattern.

Here's a sample text featuring a hopefully at least near-complete inventory of actual variants and fake variants (such as parentheses with less than four numbers) of citations in manuscripts:

```
samp <- c("Irony closely co-occurs with laughter (Norrick 2003). Blahblah
          concordances of laughter episodes, a method used by Partington (2007)
          Written Academic Language Corpus (T2K-SWAL) and adopting a Searlian 
          framework, McAllister (2015). For example, the Narrative Corpus 
          (Rühlemann & O’Donnell 2012) blahblah (MICASE), which blah
          and also Author (forthcoming) and blahblah Peter & Paul (in preparation)
          for some speech acts (cf. Maynard & Leicher 2007) blahblah
          most frequent ones in English (Carter et al. 2000: 179).blah
          include evaluative prosody (e.g., Partington 2015), vagueness (O’Keeffe 2004), 
          and deixis (e.g., Rühlemann & O’Donnell 2012). blahblah

          7 Brian:  °E:rm yeah° 
          8             (1.7)
          9 UNK:    ( )
          utterance made by a non-present speaker:
          (3)    
          I mean I've been in two shops blah most influential has been Searle’s (1975)
          and Xyz et al.'s (1999) taxonomy; (see also Kok 2017; Sperber & Wilson 1986)

          7 Ena:    and I'd always been sorry that my dad 
          8     >my dad< never <<taught us ^you know>>
          (0.5)
          9 Alan:   I’ve been trying to learn it, but I haven't got very far
          (BNC KB0: 218-223; corrected transcription)")
```

The regex I've tried so far is this:

```
str_extract_all(samp, "([A-Z][a-z].*)?\\(\\w.*[^A-Z)]\\)")
```

But the matching is far from perfect; the imperfect matches are commented on in the output:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "Irony closely co-occurs with laughter (Norrick 2003)" # only "(Norrick 2003)" should match                 
 [2] "Partington (2007)"                                                       
 [3] "McAllister (2015)"                                                       
 [4] "(Rühlemann & O’Donnell 2012)"                                            
 [5] "Author (forthcoming) and blahblah Peter & Paul (in preparation)" #  should be 2 matches: "Author (forthcoming)" and "Peter & Paul (in preparation)"       
 [6] "(cf. Maynard & Leicher 2007)"                                            
 [7] "English (Carter et al. 2000: 179)"                                   
 [8] "(e.g., Partington 2015), vagueness (O’Keeffe 2004)"   # should be 2 matches: "(e.g., Partington 2015)" and "(O’Keeffe 2004)"                 
 [9] "(e.g., Rühlemann & O’Donnell 2012)"                                      
[10] "(1.7)"                       # should not match                                       
[11] "Searle’s (1975)"                                                         
[12] "Xyz et al.'s (1999) taxonomy; (see also Kok 2017; Sperber & Wilson 1986)" # should be two matches: "Xyz et al.'s (1999)" and "(see also Kok 2017; Sperber & Wilson 1986)"
[13] "(0.5)"      # should not match                                                             
[14] "(BNC KB0: 218-223; corrected transcription)" # should not match
```

Help as to how to improve the regex is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't tell regex to filter a word because "it is not an Author's name". You need to explicitly enumerate either all possible authors' names or the disallowed words. Which will render the pattern unwieldly.

Comment: You may want to get into tools like [`quanteda`](https://quanteda.io/) package.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm aware I can't tell regex not to match "Author". I could live with a match like that as I would think that the result will have to be post-edited anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own solution. The regex is indeed unwieldy but it works--not only on the small sample in the question but also on large actual manuscripts.

**STEP 1**: Load manuscript and paste it together into a single character string:

```
ms <- paste0(ms, collapse = " ")
```

**STEP 2**: define patterns for types of citations:

*Pattern 1*: match citations completely enclosed in parenthesis, e.g., "(Kok 2017 etc.)":

```
p_1 <- "\\((Mc|O’)?[A-Za-zé][^)]*\\d{4}\\)"
```

*Pattern 2*: match citations where only year etc. is enclosed in parentheses, e.g., "Kok (2017 etc.)":

```
p_2 <- "(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b\\s\\(\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\)"
```

*Pattern 3*: match citations where name is followed by stuff before parenthesis, e.g., "Kok et al.'s (2017: 1-12)":

```
p_3 <- "(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+(\\set al\\.)?(’s)?\\s\\(\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\)"
```

*Pattern 4*: match citations with 2 names before parentheses, e.g., "Kok & Kik's (2017: 1-12)":

```
p_4 <- "(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b\\s&\\s(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b(’s)?\\s\\(\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\)"
```

*Pattern 5*: match  citations with 2 names enclosed in parentheses, e.g., "(Kok & Kik 2017: 1-12)":

```
p_5 <- "\\((Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b\\s&\\s(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b\\s\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\)"
```

*Pattern 6*: match citations enclosed in parentheses and preceded by stuff,  e.g., "(e.g., Kok & Kik 2017: 1-12)":

```
p_6 <- "\\((cf\\.\\s|e\\.g\\.,\\s)?(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+(\\set al\\.)?\\s\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\)"
```

*Pattern 7*: match multi-citations in parentheses, "(cf. Kik & Kok’s 2018; Pit 2008; 23; Joe 2017)":

```
p_7 <- "\\((cf\\.|e\\.g\\.,\\s)?(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-z][^)]*\\d{4}(: \\d+)?;(\\scf\\. also)?\\s(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-z][^)]*\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\)"
```

*Pattern 8*: match citations in square brackets, e.g., "(but see Kik & Kok’s [2018]; cf. also [Pet 2008: 23])":

```
p_8 <- "(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b\\s&\\s(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b(’s)?\\s\\[\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\]|\\[(Mc|O’)?[A-Z][a-zé]+\\b\\s\\d{4}(: \\d+)?\\]"
```

**STEP 3**: combine patterns and apply them to manuscript:

Combine:

```
allpatterns <- paste(c(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6,p_7, p_8), collapse="|")
```

Extract using `str_extract`:

```
str_extract_all(ms, allpatterns)
```

**STEP 4**: post-process result

Save:

```
cit <- str_extract_all(ms, allpatterns)
```

Split multi-citations, eg, "(A 2000; B 1999; ...)":

```
cit_split <- unlist(str_split(unlist(cit), ";\\s"))
```

Clean up:

```
cit_clean <- gsub("\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]|:\\s\\d+(-\\d+)?|(e\\.g\\.,|see also|cf.(\\salso)?)\\s|'s|’s|;", "", cit_split)
```

Order unique citations alphabetically :

```
cit_unique <- sort(unique(cit_clean))
```

**That's it**. You should now have an orderly ordered list of all citations in the manuscript!

*Disclaimer*: The patterns defined above capture many citation formats but not all! Do feel free to adapt the code to your needs and contingencies.